# How to cut a circular part from an image?

Tags: html, css, svg, clip-path

I am trying to clip my image with an SVG path but my image doesn't seem to fit in well.

This is what I am trying to achieve:
[image: CSS cut image circular part]

And this is what i am getting:

[image]

This is the code I've tried:

```css
.topbar-chat-img {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  object-fit: cover;
  clip-path: url(#topbar-img-svg);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1069" class="topbar-chat-img" />

<svg>
                    <defs>
                        <clipPath id="topbar-img-svg">
                            <path class="svg-cls" d="M33,66A33.009,33.009,0,0,1,20.155,2.593,32.99,32.99,0,0,1,66,33a32.691,32.691,0,0,1-3.271,14.341,11.008,11.008,0,0,0-13.148,14.2A32.978,32.978,0,0,1,33,66Z"/>
                        </clipPath>
                    </defs>
                </svg>
```

I was also trying to change vievBox and size of svg but i couldn't fit the image.

Comment: why clip-path? and not simply radius?

Comment: Look again at what I am trying to achieve, this is not a simple circle, it is a circle with a cut-out path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another easier way to do with SVG:

```css
body {
  background:pink;
}
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="200">
  <defs>
    <mask id="hole">
      <circle r="100" cx="100" cy="100" fill="white"/>
      <circle r="50" cx="180" cy="180" fill="black"/>
    </mask>
  <pattern id="img" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="200" height="200">
    <image  xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1069" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" />
  </pattern>
  </defs>
  <!-- create a rect, fill it with the image and apply the above mask -->
  <rect fill="url(#img)" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#hole)" />
</svg>
```

You can also do this using CSS and mask:

```css
body {
  background:pink;
}

img {
  border-radius:50%;
  -webkit-mask:radial-gradient(circle at calc(100% - 20px) calc(100% - 20px),transparent 50px,#fff 51px);
          mask:radial-gradient(circle at calc(100% - 20px) calc(100% - 20px),transparent 50px,#fff 51px);
  
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1069" >
```

Another syntax where you can easily adjust the position of the circle:

```css
body {
  background:pink;
}

img {
  border-radius:50%;
  padding:1px;
  -webkit-mask:
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,#fff 98%,transparent 100%) 
      bottom -30px right -30px/
      100px 100px no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-composite:source-out;
  
  mask:
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,#fff 98%,transparent 100%) 
      bottom -30px right -30px/
      100px 100px no-repeat;
  mask-composite:exclude;
  transition:1s;
}
img:hover {
  -webkit-mask-position:top -30px right -30px;
          mask-position:top -30px right -30px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1069" >
```

Comment: Great @temani, I have a question regarding this, this will work cross browsers?

Comment: @AtulRajput the CSS mask version will work everywhere except IE (https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks) but the SVG one should work with IE