# Mask/Crop the top right corner of button

Tags: html, css, vue.js, sass

i would like to mask the top right corner of the button to place a badge in the masked/croped part of the button like this.

[image]  [image]

Right image is what i have

i tried to do something like in this answer:
[How to cut a circular part from an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51376146/how-to-cut-a-circular-part-from-an-image)

But it seems the mask is applied only to images, not to buttons

this is a snippet code from my app

```
          <b-button pill
                    class="notification"
                    :class="{ actived: isActive}"
                    @click="showNotif">
            <b-icon-bell></b-icon-bell>
            <span class="badge">3</span>
          </b-button>
```

```
 // in my Scss file
 .notification {
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      background-color: $white;
      margin-right: 3%;
      border-color: transparent;
      & .b-icon {
        margin: 0 0 0 -4px;
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
        font-family: FuturaStd;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-stretch: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        line-height: normal;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        text-align: center;
        color: $bluey-grey;
      }

      .badge {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        padding: 3px 6px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: $golden-yellow;
        color: white;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for answering, but i found a solution like yours
i added just before my badge span a

`<span class="badge-hide"></span>`

And i applied this css

```
      .badge-hide {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        margin-left: 2px;
        padding: 9px 9px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: #f2f5f8;
        color: white;
      }

      .badge {
        position: absolute;
        top: 8px;
        margin-left: 3px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: #eec710;
        color: white;
      }
```

Result: [image]

Comment: I think perhaps the only downfall of that is now you have to adjust both classes if you change the positioning on either of them. Glad you figured it out though :)

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to wrap the yellow circle in another div to give it that couple pixels of space. So add a wrapper around badge that has 2px or 3px or 4px of padding.

```
<div class="badge-wrapper">
  <span class="badge">3</span>
</div>
```

```
.badge-wrapper {
  background-color: grey; // same as the background
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

Then move the positioning css from the badge to the wrapper.