# How to group two images together

Tags: html, css

I want to group two images together so that when zooming out it doesn't disassemble.
So what I want to achieve is like in the below image.

I tried the below code, it does work well, but when I try to zoom the page, both image get separated, so I want to group them together like in MS Word, when clicking on an image, there's an option named "Group" that assemble two images together.

I used the code in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51376146/how-to-cut-a-circular-part-from-an-image) but both images get separated when zooming in.

Otherwise, if you do have a good way of achieving it, do suggest.

```css
.partners-images-1 {
  width: 8%;
  height: 8%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-mask: radial-gradient(circle at calc(100px) calc(100px), transparent 20px, yellow 5px);
}

.partner1-logo-music {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: green;
  fill: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="partners-images-cut-out-frame">
  <img src="~/Content/images/partner1.jpg" class="partners-images-1" />
  <div class="frame-image-partner-1">
    <img src="~/Content/images/music.svg" class="partner1-logo-music" />
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: images]

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Try this code. You can change  .partners-images-cut-out-frame height and width to view the changes. or else you can zoom and check.
```

Working Example - https://www.kingsubash.com/sample-code/08062020-1
 -->

```
<!-- CSS CODE -->
.partners-images-cut-out-frame{height:350px;width:350px;} // Just change the height and width and enjoy. Both Outer image and edit icon will be in in a group
.partners-images-1 {    
  width: 15%;
  height: 15%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  left: 80%;
  bottom: 27%;
}


.partner1-logo-music {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: green;
  fill: yellow;
}


<!-- HTML CODE -->
<div class="partners-images-cut-out-frame">
  <img src="https://www.kingsubash.com/assets/img/king-subash.jpg" class="partner1-logo-music" /><!-- PROFILE ICON -->
  <img src="https://www.kingsubash.com/assets/img/kingsubash-line-art-sm.jpeg" class="partners-images-1" /> <!-- EDIT ICON -->
</div>
```

Comment: @K Subash Chandra   Thank you Loosie94 I'm testing your code now. Indeed I also created a new issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62281217/when-zooming-in-html-element-get-misplaced) , please if you can help

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a clip mask for your image?
I did the same thing with a border outside the music icon.
It works well, even if you zoom in. Here's the code and fiddle:

HTML:

```
<div class="partners-images-cut-out-frame">
   <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/any" class="partners-images-1" />
  <div class="frame-image-partner-1">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/80/80/any" class="partner1-logo-music" />
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.partners-images-cut-out-frame {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

.partners-images-1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.partner1-logo-music {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0.3125rem solid white;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -0.3125rem; /* - border radius size */
  right: -0.3125rem; /* - border radius size */
}
```

And the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Loosies/jvuhw52z/

Comment: Thank you Loosie94 I'm testing your code now. Indeed I also created a new issue   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62281217/when-zooming-in-html-element-get-misplaced)   , please if you can help.

Comment: Indeed, my image is an SVG image, not a JPG or PNG. So I'm using it normally as any other image with *<img>* tag and it's diffult yo create rounded around it that's why I'm using a <div> as frame.