# When zooming In HTML Element get misplaced

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tried the whole day of yesterday to make my page responsive when **Zooming In** but can't achieve it.
Even added **height** and **weight** but still mixing up elements when zooming in the page.

I searched many web page and tried each of them but still can't achieve it.

Not sure what to do, I'm stuck.

```css
.container-header-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.top-menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.logo-name-wording {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  top: 43px;
  left: 230px;
}

.link-top-menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  font-family: MontserratExtraLight;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.container-header-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}

.signup-frame-btn {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 38px;
  right: 270px;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.login-frame-btn {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  right: 390px;
}

.contact-frame-btn {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  right: 460px;
}

.blog-frame-btn {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  right: 550px;
}

.partners-frame-btn {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  right: 620px;
}

.activities-frame-btn {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  right: 720px;
}

.share-your-dream-top {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 37%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
  font-family: MontserratExtraBold;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.share-your-dream-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  top: 47%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
  font-family: MontserratExtraBold;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.find-perfect-friend {
  position: absolute;
  top: 58%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
  font-family: RobotoLight;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.find-holiday {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
  font-family: MontserratSemiBold;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid none;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-color: #FF4E50;
}

.meet-partner {
  margin-top: 58px;
  color: #444444;
  font-family: MontserratSemiBold;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container-header-image">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/80/80/any" alt="header-picture" style="width:100%;" class="image-background" />
    <div class="top-menu">
      <span class="logo-name-wording">TRAVELLING</span>
      <span class="link-top-menu">
                            <span class="activities-frame-btn">Menu 1</span>
      <span class="partners-frame-btn">Menu 2</span>
      <span class="blog-frame-btn">Menu 3</span>
      <span class="contact-frame-btn">Menu 4</span>
      <span class="login-frame-btn">Menu 5</span>
      <span class="signup-frame-btn">Menu 6</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="share-your-dream-top">
      <span>TELL YOUR</span>
    </div>
    <div class="share-your-dream-bottom">
      <span>TRAVEL EXPERIENCE</span>
    </div>
    <div class="find-perfect-friend">
      <span>And find the perfect friend to tell</span>
    </div>
    <div class="find-holiday">
      <span>Find your friend</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

On JSFiddle, it doesn't show properly if the zoom is at 100%; so you need to zoom out to 50% or less to see the whole page. But in a browser it's displaying properly in 100%.

[jsFiddle_Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Alice007/Lx6dn79h/1/)

Comment: @Sifat Haque Thank you Sifat Haque for your changes.

Comment: did you add this line of code in the `head` tags? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: If you want the layout to be better when you zoom, yo should use relative units instead of hard coded pixels. See https://www.24a11y.com/2019/pixels-vs-relative-units-in-css-why-its-still-a-big-deal/

Comment: @RamondeVries I added but no effect. Still misplacing elements

Comment: Can you explain why you want it responsive on zoom, of make an illustration how you want it to be? If you want this, please note that you should get rid of the pixels and use rem values or vw values because when you zoom pixels the browser can' calculate pixels correctly.

Comment: @Loosie94  I'm not an advanced dev in CSS, so my definition of **responsive** is a page that can zoom in or out properly without deteriorating its HTML elements on a browser and mobile phone. Now I'm focusing on browser first.

Comment: @Loosie94  Can you please give me a sample CSS code on how to use **rem** or **vw** ?

Answer (score 5):

For responsive design you should limit the use of `px`, `left`, `top` CSS properties, and be very cautious with `position: absolute`. And completely abandon this use of `translate` that you have.

It is better to use relative units (like `%` or `vh`, `vw`, ...), which are responsive.

And it becomes easier when you use flexbox CSS.

Here is one set of CSS you could use. You can alter the values to better match your wishes (those that have `vh` unit), or you can switch from `vh` to `vmin` units. It all depends on what you expect:

```css
html, body, header {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container-header-image {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 100%;
  color: white;
  background: url(https://placeimg.com/80/80/any);
  background-size: cover;  
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.top-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding-bottom: 25vh;
}

.logo-name-wording {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 4vh;
  text-align: center;
}

.link-top-menu {
  font-family: MontserratExtraLight;
  font-size: 3vh;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.link-top-menu * {
  margin-left: 3vh;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
}

.signup-frame-btn {
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 0.7vh 3vh 0.7vh 3vh;
  border-radius: 3vh;
}

.share-your-dream-top, .share-your-dream-bottom {
  font-family: MontserratExtraBold;
  font-size: 8vh;
  text-align: center;
}

.find-perfect-friend {
  font-family: RobotoLight;
  font-size: 6vh;
  text-align: center;
}

.find-holiday {
  text-align: center;
}

.find-holiday * {
  font-family: MontserratSemiBold;
  font-size: 5vh;
  border: 0.5vh solid none;
  padding: 1vh 4vh 1vh 4vh;
  border-radius: 4vh;
  background-color: #FF4E50;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container-header-image">
    <div class="top-menu">
      <span class="logo-name-wording">TRAVELLING</span>
      <span class="link-top-menu">      
        <span class="activities-frame-btn">Menu 1</span>
        <span class="partners-frame-btn">Menu 2</span>
        <span class="blog-frame-btn">Menu 3</span>
        <span class="contact-frame-btn">Menu 4</span>
        <span class="login-frame-btn">Menu 5</span>
        <span class="signup-frame-btn">Menu 6</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="share-your-dream-top">
      <span>TELL YOUR</span>
    </div>
    <div class="share-your-dream-bottom">
      <span>TRAVEL EXPERIENCE</span>
    </div>
    <div class="find-perfect-friend">
      <span>And find the perfect friend to tell</span>
    </div>
    <div class="find-holiday">
      <span>Find your friend</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

With this approach, zooming has hardly any effect. The responsiveness kicks in when you resize the container.

NB: I don't think "Tell your experience" is good English. Consider "Share your experience", or "Tell about your experience". Similarly, "find a friend to tell" should be "find a friend to share it with".

Answer (score 0):

Responsive means your web page is in the best position, and it shouldn't need zooming!

People think responsive means that elements need to change to different sizes. Of course that's true, but we also make a page responsive by changing elements so that the user wouldn't need to zoom any more. They can zoom in not-responsive web sites already!

If you wouldn't let the user zoom on your page, would that solve your problem? If so, add this `meta` element to your `head` section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Developers usually don't care about zooming bugs in responsive pages. Why would you need zooming any way when a page has a good lay out?

Do users need zooming on your page?

Comment: Please don't break the zoom feature of the browser, I understand the layout can get funky when I zoom but sometimes I want to zoom in on something

Comment: He says the web is responsive, users don't need zooming.
So tell me why we do responsive?
That means the web is responding you in every single device size.!
If you zoom on something thats your problem not the developer

Comment: Exactly, I am OK with the layout getting a bit messy when I zoom in.

Comment: @ꜱᴏʜᴇʟʟ Thank you so much for reply. I thought **responsive** means even I zoom, it will display the web page properly, but now I see I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend, that instead of using 'position', 'relative' and hard coding exact values, that you use FlexBox or the bootstrap grid system (which is based on flexbox) This will ensure that your website scales down perfectly and elements can adapt to the screen size.

Here are a couple of links:

````
https://getbootstrap.com
https://youtu.be/K74l26pE4YA
https://youtu.be/-Wlt8NRtOpo
https://youtu.be/qmPmwdshCMw
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox```
````