# How to make a full width overlay with masked portions

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, mask

I'm trying to make a massive overlay for a site using css masks. It doesn't seem to work however. I have created a div to be the overlay and then made an svg with some cut-outs to be my masked portions. I expect to see the specified shape cut-out, but I can't see anything of the sort.

```css
body{
    background: red;  
 }
 .overlay{
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background-color: white;
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     z-index: 1000;  
     opacity: 0.8;
 }
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <mask id="hole">
     <rect width="100" height="100" fill="blue"/>  
     <rect x="200" y="100" width="100" height="100" fill="yellow"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
</svg>
  <div class='overlay'
         mask="url(#hole)"></div>
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

PS: I think this is the most straightforward approach for my use-case. I'm trying to insert page markers into third party sites and then create a whole page overlay which fades out the website background, but leaves only my markers fully visible. I considered using clip-path, but it seems that does the reverse of what I need. I want something that shows my image, except for the positions/shapes specified.

Comment: Your SVG is invalid, you should not make the div inside the svg element. Check this to know how to correctly use mask: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51377952/8620333

Comment: I've updated the question to bring the div out of the svg, and still have the same issue. When I try to inspect, I can see the cut-out shape correctly inserted, it's just not visible.

Comment: check the link I shared, it's not only the div the issue. There is no mask attribute for div element ... take the time to understand how to apply a mask to a div